# Selecting rows with groupby, summing columns and creating new column with the sum for all groupby elements

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
nome       code  tipo   score
Alexandre   AAA  Frads  4000
Alexandre   AAA  Memb   10000
Alexandre   AAA  Memb   20000
Bruno       BBB  Dans   10000
Bruno       BBB  Grap   4000
```

[Values available in this Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRibP52tqoHEHr1xcJgx0J-ecmaJ6NA24rb6p9IZlNM/edit#gid=0)

I need to create a new column summing the rows with same `nome` and `code` where `tipo = 'Memb'`, in a way that it looks like this:

[image]

I tried `groupby` with `transform('sum')` however it is getting me the wrong result.

```
df['score'].loc[df['tipo'] == "Memb"]=df[['nome','code','score']].groupby(['nome','code'])['score'].transform('sum')
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include dataframes that I can copy and paste, I could work on a solution right now but I don't want to type everything in... check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, added a Google Sheets link, does it solve it?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRibP52tqoHEHr1xcJgx0J-ecmaJ6NA24rb6p9IZlNM/edit#gid=0

Comment: It's better in the question itself but it prevents having to type it in, thanks.

Comment: I've posted an answer, please check it if that solves your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For improve performance is possible replace `score` to `0` values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum`:

```
df['Memb_sum']  = (df.assign(score=df['score'].mask(df['tipo'] != 'Memb', 0))
                     .groupby(['nome','code'])['score']
                     .transform('sum'))
print (df)
        nome code   tipo  score  Memb_sum
0  Alexandre  AAA  Frads   4000     30000
1  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  10000     30000
2  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  20000     30000
3      Bruno  BBB   Dans  10000         0
4      Bruno  BBB   Grap   4000         0
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(score=df['score'].mask(df['tipo'] != 'Memb', 0)))

        nome code   tipo  score
0  Alexandre  AAA  Frads      0
1  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  10000
2  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  20000
3      Bruno  BBB   Dans      0
4      Bruno  BBB   Grap      0
```

Comment: By the way, it would be good if there was a version of `transform` that got passed the whole group, similar to `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

Set `'tipo'` as index using [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then group values with similar `nome` and `code` using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and use [`df.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html#pandas.DataFrame.transform) and sum of those indices which are equal to `Memb`

```
df['Memb_sum'] =  (df.set_index('tipo').
                     groupby(['nome','code']).score.
                     transform(lambda x:x.loc[x.index=='Memb'].sum()).
                     values)
```

Output:

```
        nome code   tipo  score  Memb_sum
0  Alexandre  AAA  Frads   4000     30000
1  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  10000     30000
2  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  20000     30000
3      Bruno  BBB   Dans  10000         0
4      Bruno  BBB   Grap   4000         0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

df['Memb_sum']=df.groupby(['nome','code','tipo'])['score'].transform('sum')

df['Memb_sum']=np.where(df['tipo'] != 'Memb', 0, df['Memb_sum'])

df['Memb_sum']=df.groupby(['nome','code'])['Memb_sum'].transform('max')
```

You can perform group by first and later filter out values.

Output:

```
        nome code   tipo  score  Memb_sum
0  Alexandre  AAA  Frads   4000     30000
1  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  10000     30000
2  Alexandre  AAA   Memb  20000     30000
3      Bruno  BBB   Dans  10000         0
4      Bruno  BBB   Grap   4000         0
```