# Groupby and sum by 1 column, keep all other columns, and mutate a new column, counting summed rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am new to Python and can see at least [5 similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Groupby+and+sum+by+1+column%2C+keep+all+other+columns%2C+and+mutate+a+new+column%2C+counting+summed+rows+with+pandas&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS891US891&oq=Groupby+and+sum+by+1+column%2C+keep+all+other+columns%2C+and+mutate+a+new+column%2C+counting+summed+rows+with+pandas&aqs=chrome..69i57.358j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and this one is [very close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115668/selecting-rows-with-groupby-summing-columns-and-creating-new-column-with-the-su) but non of them work for me.

I have a dataframe with non-unique customers.

```
  customer_id   amount  male age    income     days reward   difficulty    duration
0   id_1       16.06    1    45     62000.0    608   2.0        10.0         10.0
1   id_1       18.00    1    45     62000.0    608   2.0        10.0         10.0
```

I am trying to group them by `customer_id`, sum by `amount` and **keep all other columns PLUS add one column `total`, counting my transactions**

Desired output

```
  customer_id amount   male age    income      days reward   difficulty duration total
 0  id_1       34.06    1    45     62000.0    608   2.0      10.0       10.0      2
```

My best personal attempt so far does not preserve all columns

```
groupby('customer_id')['amount'].agg(total_sum = 'sum', total = 'count')
```

[image]

Comment: First thing is that you are not grouping by `amount` please check and write more description of what other columns do!.

Comment: Thanks, I updated, it was my mistake. Group by customer_id and sum by amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way, include all other columns in your groupby then reset_index after aggregating:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['amount']).tolist())['amount']\
  .agg(total_sum='sum',total='count').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   age customer_id  days  difficulty  duration   income  male  reward  total_sum  total
0   45        id_1   608        10.0      10.0  62000.0     1     2.0      34.06      2
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! That was exactly I was looking for!

Comment: Scott, sorry, are you grouping by customer_id or amount? Not sure. I need to group by customer _id.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker This is grouping on all column EXCEPT for 'amount' including customer_id. This works a single customer has only one set of values for all other columns except amount.

Comment: Scott, how would you do the same, if my unique customers have different values in  columns like `difficulty`, `duration`,  `reward`? Rows in these columns are not the same and I am trying now to calculate average for `difficulty` and `duration` and sum for `reward`.

Answer (score 3):

you could do:

```
grouper = df.groupby('customer_id')
first_dict = {col: 'first' for col in df.columns.difference(['customer_id', 'amount'])}
o = grouper.agg({
     'amount': 'size', 
     **first_dict,
})
o['total'] = grouper.size().values
```

Comment: SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported

Comment: my bad, mispelled male, I didn't get the same error as you, but now it should work as it works for me

Comment: which version of pandas you are using ?

Comment: I edited my code, it will probably work now regardless of your version

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe you can give a tip how to keep columns in my code? Thanks!

Comment: I also think that in your code customer_id is an index now :(

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Scott Boston's answer, I found an answer myself too and I acknowledge that my solution is not elegant (maybe something will help to clean it). But it gives me an expanded solution, when I have non-unique rows (for instance, each `customer_id` has five different transactions).

```
df.groupby('customer_id').agg({'amount':['sum'], 'reward_':['sum'], 'difficulty':['mean'], 
                                            'duration':['mean'], 'male':['mean'], 'male':['mean'], 
                                            'income':['mean'], 'days':['mean'], 'age':['mean'], 
                                            'customer_id':['count']}).reset_index()

df_grouped = starbucks_grouped.droplevel(1, axis = 1)
```

My output is

[image]